# Extracting Phrase After A Special Character In Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

Please see one of the phrases as example below
`Start -> vendor-i (06/06/2017 09:07:18 PM) -> vendor-p (06/08/2017 04:44:47 PM) -> vendor-p (06/12/2017 11:32:33 AM) -> vendor-p (06/13/2017 04:49:47 PM)`
From the above phase i need to extract vendor-i as a new variable and then vendor-p as another new variable.
There could be scenario where I have only one of the vendor names.

The code I have built is:
`regexp_extract(GROUP_NAMES,r'([a-z\._]*)\.') as integrations,
      regexp_extract(GROUP_NAMES,r([vendor_que]) as vendor_que`

Please suggest how we can achieve this as the vendor name can appear anywhere so we cant also define a length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want all of the names, you can use `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` to get an array of them. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(GROUP_NAMES, r'-> ([^ ]+)')
FROM (
  SELECT 'Start -> vendor-i (06/06/2017 09:07:18 PM) -> vendor-p (06/08/2017 04:44:47 PM) -> vendor-p (06/12/2017 11:32:33 AM) -> vendor-p (06/13/2017 04:49:47 PM)' AS GROUP_NAMES
);
```

The output is the array `["vendor-i", "vendor-p", "vendor-p", "vendor-p"]`.

Comment: Perfect this is what i was after, but if you dont mind explaining what is this part of the formula doing ([^ ]+)'). Sorry but tried searching a lot of supporting document cannot apprehend.

Comment: Yeah, sure. What that will do is to match every character until the next space. The `[^ ]` indicates any character except space, and the `+` means at least one match. The parentheses mean to capture the contents that are selected by the expression. You might be able to find some regular expression tutorials online that will help.